# Why was Philip K Dick so distressed at Ridley Scott's adaptation of 'Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep'?

Tags: blade-runner, blade-runner-series, philip-k-dick, do-androids-dream-of-electric-sheep

I have heard this a couple of times now but I don't know the reasoning behind this. I know that the film adaptation of the novel was released shortly before the authors death.

Also, if this is the case, what was Ridley Scott's response to his distress?

Comment: Thanks for the link there. However, I heard that his take on the film was not what he had imagined and that he was not impressed. 
Perhaps I have been misinformed though.

Comment: Given that letter he wrote and how he died inbetween the letter and the movie's release it seems pretty unlikely that he had a problem with it. Do you perhaps have a link to anyone claiming he did?

Comment: Will research and see what I can come up with.

Comment: After some 'quick' research, it seems he had a problem with early scripts (Herb Jaffe). Considering how long ago it was actually written. 
I have just seen some information from a fan website:
[Link](http://www.philipkdickfans.com/mirror/websites/pkdweb/BLADE%20RUNNER.htm)

Perhaps this is what was actually meant when I read the report (I cannot remember where now as it was a while ago but was always something I sort of thought about...)

Comment: *Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep* wasn't a short story, it was a novel...

Comment: @evilsoup Agreed. I just edited the original question.

Comment: Yes, thanks all for amendments and answers.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

"*Why was Philip K Dick so distressed...*"
Easy answer; he wasn't.

If you read [Mike Scott's](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/23/mike-scott) [excellent answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/373/did-philip-dick-watch-blade-runner-before-his-death), you will see that, although he never saw the completed version, what he did see impressed him significantly enough that he sent a glowingly complimentary letter to the production company, thanking them for their contribution to the field of SciFi, which he felt had been stagnating.

Comment: Yeah, I read it. PKD did feel that SciFi was stagnating and that the original scripts were extremely sub-par. 
However, his attitude obviously changed when a new script was written in 1980 and submitted in 1981. Upon seeing an unfinished version of the film he was obviously delighted.
Thanks all who helped answer my question.

Comment: You mean the field of futurism ;-)

Comment: Yes, the field of futurism!! =]